# How to set the position of stack in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I face some problem while using stack in flutter. The problem is there are 9 container in a row. First of all I use stack to put the map pin image at the first container. Then after I roll the dices and get the number 6, I need to move the map pin image to the number 6 container. This are same as the monopoly game, I need to move the player based on the number. How can I do that?

```
Positioned(
        top: 310,
        left: 670,
        child: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: 30,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/player.png'),
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        )),
```

This is how I set the image at the first position. How can I move the image to the sixth container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I assume that the first one's horizontal location is 670 and the width of each box is 30. Then, this should get you to the sixth box:

```
  int nth = 6;
  double boxWidth = 30; 
  Positioned(
    top: 310,
    left: 670 + (nth - 1) * boxWidth,
    child: Container(
      height: 50,
      width: boxWidth,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/player.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
    )),

//     |-30-|-30-|-30-|-30-|-30-|-30-|
//     |                        | 
//    670                   670+5*30
```

And to have both X and Y positioning, you can use this:

```
  int nthX = 6;
  int nthY = 5;
  double boxWidth = 30; 
  double boxHeight = 50;
  Positioned(
    top: 310 + (nthY - 1) * boxHeight,
    left: 670 + (nthX - 1) * boxWidth,
    child: Container(
      height: boxHeight,
      width: boxWidth,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('assets/images/player.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
    )),
```

Comment: Hi it work!! Thank you so much. May i ask one more thing? There are 9 container in a row and 9 container in a column. After I move 6 steps to the right, and I roll the dices again and get 7, I need to move 3 more steps to the right and 4 steps down the column. How can i set the number of top and left?

Comment: Great! See my edit for the X and Y version. If this helped you consider accepting the answer.